# Recebendo inúmeros dados com socket Python

Tags: python, socket

Eu estou com um problema no meu script, eu tenho um **server.py** e um **client.py** e meu problema é receber e enviar grandes quantidades de bytes.

Quero transferir grandes quantidades de bytes de arquivos para o client e também para o server, só que tenho uma limitação no `recv(1024)`. Ele vai receber 1024 bytes e se eu tiver uma quantidade **x** de bytes para enviar ou receber, como que posso criar isso ?

Bom eu criaria uma função própria para lidar com esse problema:

```
def recvall():
    pass
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma lógica para resolver esse problema para receber tantos bytes.

A lógica do meu script é, quando o cliente enviar um comando X para o servidor, ele envia o arquivo para o cliente, se o cliente enviar um comando Y para o servidor, o cliente tem que enviar o arquivo para o servidor.

```
#server.py
decode = lambda data: data.decode('utf-8')

def Socket():
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def accept(port):
    Socket()
    host = ''#socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        data = decode(conn.recv(1024))
        if data == 'enviarfile':
            with open('doc.pdf', 'rb') as f
                pass

# client.py
def client(port):
    host= '0.0.0.0'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    sys.exit()

print('CONNECTED\n')

while True:
    command = input('comando:')
    s.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
    if command == 'enviarfile':
        with open('doc.pdf', 'wb') as f
             pass

    if 'exit' in command:
        break
    print(s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')+'\n')
```

Essa função que eu criaria `def recvall()` não seria somente para arquivos mas também para mensagens. O cliente envia `'oi'` e imprime na tela do servidor e o servidor enviaria uma resposta que recebeu a mensagem do cliente.

Comment: O limite no `recv` faz com que a cada chamada do método ele obtenha somente 1024 bytes, mas isso não significa que você perderia o resto do bytes que foram enviados no `send`. Dito isto, você só precisa enviar todos os bytes do arquivo e obter o conteúdo com o `recv` aos poucos através de um bloco de repetição.

Comment: obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua implementação de recvall() tem de chamar recv(1024) dentro de um loop e ir acumulando os buffers recebidos. Quando recv() retornar zero, é porque o outro lado fechou a conexão e a transmissão terminou.

Outro problema é que você está enviando comandos interativos, além de arquivos, aí você vai ter de criar um protocolo, para detectar dentro do buffer recebido onde termina o comando e começa o arquivo.